# Is my regional highway ramp supposed to use power?

Tags: simcity-2013

Context: After bulldozing my entire city to start fresh with the money saved up, I found that my budget was running at -240 pr hour because of power cost to the highway ramp (to region).

Question: Is this a bug, or working as intended?

Info about the city.

- The city is on year three and I have about 4 million credits on hand
  (Maxed out taxes, turned off all the utilities, and let it run until
  I was making less than 5k pr hour. Then I bulldozed everything).
- The -240 shows up under "Power" in the budget.
- When I use the map tool for power I can see the little strip of
  highway sticking into the city (the part you can't remove) light up red. (Nothing else shows up when using all the various map data views).
- I am 100% sure that there is nothing in the city.

Speculation: Maybe there is a trigger for this once the city gets going, as a game balance element?

Comment: Now that is fairly interesting.. I have seen all the roads start out red before but I was unaware that they drew any sort of funding for power on their own with out buildings. Are you buying power from outside still?

Comment: No. I made sure that all imports of utilities was off.

Comment: Odd, Who can you be 'Paying' for power then? If you have nothing left in town generating the power to have upkeep nor are you paying externally that just seems like a bug. Something didn't unregister it's upkeep when it should have.

Comment: The same happened to me, I ended up with around $500/hour in the red, even if I bulldozed everything. I noticed there were a few things still left on the map that didn't look like trees, however... Seemed to be some leftovers from buildings, but I couldn't select or delete them. Maybe those were drawing the power somehow, I dunno...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like bulldozing buildings doesn't always properly release the 'resources' that they are using. Before taking out a 'ploppable' make sure to power it off first, check that all of the vehicles have returned then bulldoze it.